# How to assign column data into column name

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find below sql query

```
create table test_bin (date1 varchar2(10), desc varchar2(10), values number(10));
insert into test_bin values ('10DEC2015', 'ABC', 10);
insert into test_bin values ('10DEC2015', 'CDE', 20);
insert into test_bin values ('10DEC2015', 'XYZ', 35);
insert into test_bin values ('12DEC2015', 'ABC', 10);
insert into test_bin values ('12DEC2015', 'CDE', 45);
insert into test_bin values ('12DEC2015', 'XYZ', 98);
insert into test_bin values ('13DEC2015', 'ABC', 76);
insert into test_bin values ('13DEC2015', 'CDE', 86);
insert into test_bin values ('13DEC2015', 'XYZ', 63);
commit;
```

question:-
I am expecting following output, I tried my level best i can't able to get proper query

```
DESC 10DEC2015 12DEC2015 13DEC2015
ABC     10          NULL    NULL
CDE     20          NULL    NULL
XYZ     35          NULL    NULL
ABC     NULL        10      NULL
CDE     NULL        45      NULL
XYZ     NULL        98      NULL
ABC     NULL        NULL     76
CDE     NULL        NULL     86
XYZ     NULL        NULL     63
```

Comment: It's much better to store dates in `date` column not `varchar2`

Comment: HI Sagi, am using oracle 10g.

Comment: If you add another row with a new date to your table, do you expect that date to show up as a new column when you run your query?

Comment: Do you have a starting 'date' and a number of days from that to always show? Or a maximum number of 'dates' that the table may contain? Or does it need to be completely dynamic, with a variable number of columns? (Or does the question title mean you know how to manually pivot the values, but not how to set the column *name* in the result set?)

Comment: @Aleksej : Already it has been defined, we can't change data type
jarlh : we can't able to add one more new column
AlexPoole: Yes alex, this date will increase day by day.

Comment: But for a fixed window of 4 days, from some supplied start date? Or some other numbers of days? What about days with no data, like 11DEC2015 - the column should not appear? What would the output be if you added a record for 14DEC2015, or 07MAR2015? (Which is what jarlh was asking really). You need to clarify your requirements, and then show us how far you have got and what issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one way :

```
select desc, 
       SUM(case when date1='10DEC2015' then values end) as "10DEC2015",
       sum(case when date1='12DEC2015' then values end) as "12DEC2015",
       sum(case when date1='13DEC2015' then values end) as "13DEC2015"
from   test_bin
group by date1, desc;
```

It supposes that you already know all existing values for date1, except if you create dynamically your request.

*PS : be careful about using SQL keyword as column name*

*PS1 : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20068f/5, it's in **MySQL** because 10g was not available and Oracle is far away from me AND column name has been changed to avoid conflict with SQL keywords*

Comment: Oracle identifiers can't start with numbers unless they're quoted. But I think the OP wants it to be more dynamic than this as well; it still isn't clear though.